# Continuity and differentiability of $G(x) = (\alpha + |x|)^2 \exp (5- |x|)^2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Let $\alpha$ be a real number. Consider the following function.
$$G(x) = (\alpha + |x|)^2 \exp (5- |x|)^2, \ \ \ \ \ \ - \infty <x<\infty$$

Determine the values of $\alpha$ for which $g$ is continuous at all $x$ and $g$ is differentiable at all $x$.

I tried to evaluate the limit at $x$ tends to plus and minus infinity but getting wrong please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Consider the continuity/differentiable of $G$ on $(-\infty, 0)$, $(0, +\infty)$ and at a single point $x = 0$. Then,it should be cleared that the only requirement for $G$ to be continuous and differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ is to be continuous and differentiable at $x = 0$

Comment: Check the continuity and differentiability at x=0. Because, at all other x, it is continuous and differentiable, as G it is a product of a polynomial and exponential function.

Comment: Pick some value of $\alpha$. Now plot $G(x)$ for this value of $\alpha$. What do you see? Does the shape of the curve suggest where $G(x)$ could be discontinuous or non-differentiable? Visualization functions is a really great way to get insights.